# Continuous $f$ such that $\int_1^2 f(x)\, \mathrm dx = 0$, show that there exists $1 \lt c \lt 2$, such that $c f(c) = \int_c^2 f(x)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Let $f\colon [1,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that$$\int_1^2 f(x)\, \d x = 0.$$ Show that there exists $1 < c < 2$, such that$$c f(c) = \int_c^2 f(x)\,\d x.$$

I understand that I can split the integral and rewrite it as$$\int_1^c f(x)\,\d x + \int_c^2 f(x)\,\d x = 0,$$ but I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 4):

Let $F(x)=\int_x^2 f(t) \mathrm{d}t$. Then $F'(x)=-f(x)$ and $F(1)=F(2)=0$. Now apply [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem)  to $x F(x)$.